# Required attribute for property that is not required in the database

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I have a form, where some fields are mandatory. A few of the mandatory fields have not always been mandatory, hence there are null values in the database.

If I add [Required] for the property, I will get a SqlNullValueException, because there are null values in the database.

What is the best practice to get a field to behave as if it had a [Required] attribute?

```
[Required]
public string? foo { get; set; }
```

Comment: You can create a [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) for this form and map it to the entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're a bit light on context here, but I assume you are using Entity Framework and you have a `class` setup for the entity and this is what has your `[required]` field. I am then assuming you are using this same class with your form.

If this is the case then, I would advise you to create a second `class` which will act as your view model. This way you have a data model (entity class) and a view model (front end specific class). Then you can easily separate the logic of the two behaviours.

You can use something like AutoMapper to make transferring of property values between the two a little easier too.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear but you are absolutely correct.
Thanks for the advise regarding the second class (ViewModel)